# i have requirement in angular 4 to read data from jspn file - 'dashboard.json' and insert in html table. I am trying to use .map on observable

Tags: json, angular

I am new to angular 4 and so need guidance on how to read data from json file and display in table in html page. Please if anyone can share sample code it would be great help

Comment: You will have to give more details about what you are trying to achieve, as well as what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: I am new to angular 4 and so need guidance on how to read data from json file and display in table in html page. Please if anyone can share sample code it would be great help!

Comment: You are using HttpClient? Post some code, error message etc.